# generate a random number within a range but exclude some in C/C++

Tags: c, algorithm

Not a new question but its specific to only c/c++ .

```
For ex- range[1...10] exclude_set [2,5,7,9]
```

Custom rand function should return remaining numbers with equal probability.

What i have tried is-

1) generate number by rand() %10 function .

2) check if values is present in exclude_Set .if present call rand() again in loop

Interviewer said its brute force approach .I am curious that is there any good algorithm present for c/c++

The question is already answered for Java/C#/PHP on SO

[How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443176/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some)

[How to get a random value from 1~N but excluding several specific values in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698265/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-1n-but-excluding-several-specific-values-in-php)

[How to get a random number from a range, excluding some values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484577/how-to-get-a-random-number-from-a-range-excluding-some-values)

**PS**- I have already tried googling.Even Bing

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language, pick one please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok let say in C.I am more concentrated on algorithm.

Comment: I am not sure why down vote on this question??

Comment: If you're just interested in the algorithm, remove the language tags at all please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Although i have removed c++ tag but i think its bit language specific because in c/c++ there is no support of `nextInt` like in Java/C#

Comment: @Olaf Exclude_Set may have any number not even or odd.

Comment: Shan, @NathanOliver: Sorry, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straightforward way is to map the remaining values to an array and use `rand()` to access them, something like:

```
int[6] rvec = {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10};
// and get numbers with
rvec[rand() % 6];
```

Comment: Having all allowed values in a vector/array is quite a wast of space and not acceptable for large sets. Also this will not distribute random values evenly.

Comment: @Olaf OP changed to C from C/C++.  Edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For small sets up to e.g. 64 bits, you can use a bitmap with excluded (or included) values:

```
#define MAX_RANDVAL 10

uint64_t illegal_values = (1ULL<<2) | (1ULL<<5) | ... ;
int rand_val;

do {
    rand_val = rand();
} while ( (rand_val > MAX_RANDVAL) || (illegal_values & (UINT64_C(1) << rand_val) );
```

However, to get evenly distributed values, you have to loop if an illegal value is encountered.

Enhancements might include exploiting regularities in the sequence. The range may be extended using a hash-algorithm or even a binary search tree. The optimal algorithm heavily depends on the actual requirements. There is no single **best** algorithm.

Comment: The while()-expression is always false, since if rand_val is greater than MAX_RANDVAL, illegal_values & (1ULL << rand_val) will probably not be true at the same time (assuming that no illegal values greater than MAX_RANDVAL are flagged in the bitmask). Did you perhaps mean to use a logical disjunction?

Comment: @Ctx: Thanks , edited. Also corrected a minor flaw with the mask (not critical).